# ActionBar Overlay

Tags: android-actionbar, overlay, transparent

When I add this line to my ActionBarStyle:

```
  <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

and in my layout I add this :

```
  android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

The ActionBar won't be transparent.
picture : [image]

Comment: Is it what you're looking for?
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: yes, i do with this tutorial, but the action bar wont be transparent..

Comment: I was refering to the tip sending you there : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

You basically need to use your custom layout for the actionbar, where you'll be able to set the transparency you want

Answer (score 2):

Define your new actionbar background like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Where

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

will be where you set up your actionbar background, as a drawable, a color, or whatever else you want.

And then apply this theme to whatever activity or the whole application :

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

EDIT : 
Is this what you're looking for?
[image: transparent actionbar]

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" when i add this code it isn't transparent

Comment: i want that the list view is in action bar when i take it down

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you will need to use the **AppCompat** library from the Android SDK. I used appcompat_v7.

For **Android 2.1 and higher**, I solved the problem by adding the following line in my **styles.xml** file in your **res/values** folder:

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

For example:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

As for **Android 3.0 and higher only**, I added the following line in both the **styles.xml** file in the **res/values-v11** folder as well as the other **styles.xml** file in the **res/values-v14** folder:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

For example:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I hope this will help.